# Python Code Optimization (For-Loop & If-else) Advice for quicker computation time

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, if-statement, pyspark

Need to reduce the computation for the following python code which contains multiple if else statements. The code runs on a DataBricks so I'm open to Pyspark Solutions as well.
Currently this code takes more than 1 hour to run. So any help would be appreciated.

`unique_list_code`: List of Unique code from `concat_df['C_Code']` column used to filter rows of dataframe containing the code.
`concat_df`:Pandas DataFrame with 4 million records

```
unique_list_code = list(concat_df['C_Code'].unique())
MC_list =[]
SN_list =[]
AN_list = []
Nothing_list =[]
for i in range(0,len(unique_list_code)):
  
  print(unique_list_code[i])
  code_filtered_df = concat_df[concat_df['C_Code'] == unique_list_code[i]]
  
  #SN_Filter:
  SN_filter = code_filtered_df[(code_filtered_df['D_Type'] == 'SN') & (code_filtered_df['Comm_P'] == 'P-mail')]
  if len(SN_filter)>0:
    print("Found SN")
    SN_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
    clean_up(SN_filter)
  else:
    #AN_Filter
    AN_filter = code_filtered_df[(code_filtered_df['D_Type'] == 'AN') & (code_filtered_df['Comm_P'] == 'P-mail')]
    if len(AN_filter)>0:
      print("Found AN")
      AN_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
      clean_up(AN_filter)
    else:
      #MC_Check
      MF_filter = code_filtered_df[code_filtered_df['MC_Flag'] =='Y' ]
      MF_DNS_filter = MF_filter[~(((MF_filter['D_Type'] == 'AN')| (MF_filter['D_Type'] =='SN')) &  (MF_filter['Comm_P'] == 'DNS'))]
      
      if len(MF_DNS_filter)>0:
        print("Found MC")
        MC_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
        clean_up(MF_DNS_filter)
      else:
        print("Nothing Found")
        Nothing_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
```

**Update:**
Changed it to Pyspark DF and the code as follows, still no luck.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    from pyspark.sql.functions import when
    MC_list =[]
    SN_list =[]
    AN_list = []
    Nothing_list =[]
    for i in range(0,len(unique_list_code)):
      code_filtered_df = df.filter(col("C_code")  == unique_list_code[i])
      SN_filter = code_filtered_df.filter((col('D_Type') == 'SN') & (col('Comm_P') == 'P-mail'))
      if SN_filter.count() >0:
        SN_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
      else:
        AN_filter = code_filtered_df.filter((col('D_Type') == 'AN') & (col('Comm_P') == 'P-mail'))
        if AN_filter.count()>0:
          AN_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
        else:
          MF_filter = code_filtered_df.filter(col('MC_Flag') =='Y')
          MF_DNS_filter = MF_filter[~(((col('D_Type') == 'AN')| (col('D_Type') =='SN')) &  (col('Comm_P') == 'DNS'))]
          if MF_DNS_filter.count()>0:
            print("Found MC")
            MC_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
          else:
            print("Nothing Found")
            Nothing_list.append(unique_list_code[i])
```

Comment: use `line_profiler` to check what is the bottleneck here

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is taking so long is that you are working with a Pandas DF

If you want to benefit from distributed computation and increase your performance, you need to work with a Spark dataframe in this case:

```
Spark_DF = spark.createDataFrame(Pandas_DF)
```

You will need to rewrite your code in PySpark to work with a Spark DF

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to rewrite this code in pyspark. Pyspark allow you distribut data through worker nodes on cluster.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

filter_condition = (((col('D_Type') == 'SN' & col('Comm_P') == 'P-mail')) OR ((col('D_Type') == 'AN' & col('Comm_P') == 'P-mail')) OR (...))

result_df = concat_df.where(filter_condition)
```

Comment: Created a spark Dataframe and used the filter functionality.
Example:
``` code_filtered_df = df.filter(col("C_code")  == unique_list_code[i])
  SN_filter = code_filtered_df.filter((col('D_Type') == 'SN') & (col('Comm_P') == 'P-mail'))
```
This still takes a long time. I'm still struggling to optimize it, i got the data downt o 400k records to search for. Any further suggestions?